# Event compositions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, rxjs

I have three $watches in a directive.

I want to **doSomething** only after all three $watch listeners have been triggered.

After **doSomething** has been called for the first time,  I then want to **doSomething** every time any one of the $watch listeners fire in the future.

I could keep track of whether the various watches have resolved before and implement my desired behaviour but I'm wondering if there is an easier way. Maybe RxJS can help me?

Naive approach below... I'd rather not track this information in my application logic.

```
var hasAResolved = false;
var hasBResolved = false;
var hasCResolved = false;
$scope.$watch('a', setAToResolvedAndMaybeDoSomething);

$scope.$watch('b', setBToResolvedAndMaybeDoSomething);

$scope.$watch('c', setCToResolvedAndMaybeDoSomething);

function doSomething(){...};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has built in [Kris Kowal's Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) style api, [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) which you can use along with the `all` function.

**EDIT**:
As per @dfsq comment I missed a key point to your question originally. I have updated to code example below to taken into account allowing `doSomething` to be called repeatedly.

```
var a = $q.defer();
var b = $q.defer();
var c = $q.defer();

$scope.$watch('a', function() {
    // do something with a
    a.resolve();
});
$scope.$watch('b', function() {
    // do something with b
    b.resolve();
});
$scope.$watch('c', function() {
    // do something with c
    c.resolve();
});

var doSomething = function() {
   // do some stuff
};

$q.all([a.promise, b.promise, c.promise]).then(function() {
   doSomething();

   // set a,b,c so that calling resolve will delgate to the `doSomething` function
   a = b = c = {
       resolve: doSomething
   };
});
```

Comment: What about *"After doSomething has been called for the first time, I then want to doSomething every time any one of the $watch listeners fire in the future."*.